# ACM problem: Number of distinct substrings of long string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This problem is taken from previous year's acm contest.
Problem:

- Given string `p` of length `k <= 1000`
- This string is repeated infinite times and now we take first `n < 10^9` characters. Let's call resulting string `s`.

The task is to find count of unique substrings of the string `s`.

Traditional way of counting distinct substrings is suffix + lcp arrays, but we need O(n) to construct them (using fastest and pretty complex construction algorithm). And after constructing these arrays we will need to do a lot of further processing, so I don't think this solution can fit time requirements.

I have read problem analysis but I don't get it at all. Of course it works perfectly, but how did they come to it?
Here it is:

- if `p = tt...t` for some string `t`, replace `p` with `t`. Now let's assume that p is non-periodic.
- `f(n)` — count of unique substrings in prefix of `s` of length `n`.
- Let's assume that `n > 2k`. Then `f(n) = f(n-1)+k`. *<- Why? What's the logic behind it?*

Proof:

- let `t` be a suffix of `s`.
- if `|t| <= n - k`, then `l` is also included to the s on k symbols to the left.

  - if `|t| > n - k`, then `l` is included to the s only as a suffix.
- for `n<=2k` problem can be solved anyhow.

Any explanations of this problem analysis or your own solutions are highly appreciated! I don't understand how can I think up that function f(). Have been thinking of this problem for few days already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that `k` is the length of the non-periodic input string `p`. For a given length `l`, there are at most `k` distinct substrings of length `l`, since every two substrings whose starting position is congruent modulo `k` are identical. The key consequence of `p` being non-periodic is that its `k` rotations are all distinct, which means that given a substring of length at least `k`, we can use its length-`k` prefix, a rotation of `p`, to determine the starting position of the substring modulo `k`. Hence for all `l` in `[k, n-k+1]`, we know that there are exactly `k` distinct substrings of length `l`. For all `l` in `[n+1-k, n]`, there are exactly `n+1-l` substrings. For all `l` in `[0, k)`, we use the usual technology to count.

Comment: Brilliant! So clear and easy to understand solution. Thank you so much!